# Why Errors Occur in the Text Composable function?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

```kotlin
@Composable
fun QuizApplication(){
    var checkedState by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(16.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)
    ) {
        Checkbox(
            checked = checkedState,
            onCheckedChange = { checkedState = it },
            modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 16.dp)
        )
        Text(text = if (checkedState) "Checkbox is checked" else "Checkbox is unchecked")
    }
}
```

Assistance with Problem Solving: Guidance and Solutions

Comment: Please add the error you are experiencing to the question

Comment: The Composable itself makes no error. I checked it. Also the your checkState changes.  
As @pochopsp suggests, please provide an error log.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.